# Give custom warning messages to the client when the client machine does not meet necessary software requirements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, message

Here this is the problem. I have a system. And the client gets the installation from a server. So when the client machine does not have any kind of a software component it throws an warning(automatically). So the client is googling it and downloading it. I want to know whether there is a method that I can give any custom warning when the client machine is missing a software component.. well I'll make this easy... like this.. 
Assume
during the first install of the program, an error was getting as a warning stating it needed report viewer.  Client does not realize the link to the report viewer was listed on top, so he went a googled it and downloaded it.. So with that in mind,  Is there any way that change the warning to say you need to install report viewer, please see menu for the download link.. like making it easy for the client... is there a method ? :) thanks in advance

Comment: Create an installer. And I don't mean ClickOnce.

Comment: so from installer can i give custom messages?

Comment: Depends on the installer you use, but a proper installer can also install prerequisites so the  user doesn't get an error at all.

Comment: please give me a proper installer.. im soo new to programming bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Visual studio itself you have `Setup Project` template using which you can create MSI/Setup package for your application and within this you have the option to specify the pre-requisites for installing your application and specify the path from where that feature can be downloaded. once you provide these options, during installation it will automatically check for pre-requisites and if pre-requisites are not installed in the client system then download it from given path after confirmation from user. on this link you can find the basic usage of Setup project to create MSI/Setup package. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Setup-Package-for-Csharp-Windows